# Smooth out resizing table cells during reload on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I have a project that includes a table that is dynamically created and formatted without using IB. The issue is, that the table needs to change both values and size during a rotation. However, the resizing is choppy and occurs suddenly during the animation. Currently I'm using the didRotate method, and in that method I'm calling the reload method in order to resize it. Should I be using a different method to do this, or is there anyway to at least smooth out the resizing?

Edit: I'm trying to use the replacement/resizing within the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:, or possibly the two step animation. However, these methods are never called, is this due to the view hierarchy (the view I'm trying to resize is part of a split view)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you tell the didRotate method to use animation when making the changes?  For example, here is a code snippet that makes a flip transition.  The key is to use the "beginAnimations" and "commitAnimations" to tell the iPhone how to handle those changes.  The code in between describes the changes.  When the "commitAnimations" is called, the changes are magically animated.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"leftPortrait" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:leftView cache:YES];
[leftWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 384, 916)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand exactly what you're doing here, but unfortunately I can't use any flip animations or such. I just need a smooth resize to occur during the rotation. I'm considering the two-part rotation, but it still doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough.  I wasn't suggesting that you use the flip transition per-se, but just using that as an example.  However, I believe if you use the beginAnimations and commitAnimations and do the resize in the middle of those statements, it should still transition smoothly, no?